# The guard doesn't notifies with growl when the specs are run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, growl

When I modify my guardfile then I receive the notification with growl, but when I modify a specfile and the specs are run I don't.

Any idea is welcome.

I have:

- growl: 2.1.3
- ruby_gntp (0.3.4)
- guard-spring (0.0.4)

And this is the end of my Guardfile:

```
notification :gntp
notification :growl
```

These notifiers are turned on:
 bundle exec guard notifiers
19:13:30 - INFO - Guard::Spring Initialized

```
+-------------------+-----------+------+------------------------+-------------------+
| Name              | Available | Used | Option                 | Value             |
+-------------------+-----------+------+------------------------+-------------------+
| gntp              | ✔         | ✔    | sticky                 | false             |
+-------------------+-----------+------+------------------------+-------------------+
| growl             | ✔         | ✔    | sticky                 | false             |
|                   |           |      | priority               | 0                 |
+-------------------+-----------+------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

If I comment the gntp and the growl options out then those won't be autodetected by guard..

Comment: Hm... It seems that it is something with the notification dispatcher because it doesn't work with the file notification neither.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when I upgraded to Mavericks.  It took Growl update to fix the problem.

Comment: Then how do you explain that I receive growl notification when the guardfile is modified?

Comment: I had the same problem and it seemed to be related to how events were sent to growl from guard.  Some worked, some didn't

Comment: Ok the problem was that I used the guard-spring gem which doesn't uses any notifier... So I switched back to guard-rspec with cmd 'spring'